# Access different panels using loop

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create multiple labels in different panels, but it keeps creating only one panel.

Here is my code

```
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For i = 0 To 7

            Dim lbl As New Label() With
                {
            .Text = "Suppliant Name:",
            .Location = New Point(117, 10 * 1),
            .Height = 15,
            .Width = 95}
            req1.Controls.Add(lbl)
            req2.Controls.Add(lbl)
            req3.Controls.Add(lbl)
            req4.Controls.Add(lbl)
            req5.Controls.Add(lbl)
            req6.Controls.Add(lbl)
            req7.Controls.Add(lbl)


        Next


    End Sub
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't create any Panels at all, so your question makes no sense as you have asked it. Please edit the question and word it correctly.

Comment: This is what happens when you write code without knowing what it actually has to do. You know what the end result is that you want but you clearly don't know what the steps are to get there, so how can you write code to preform those steps? Spend some time working out the logic first and then write that down as a formal algorithm. You can then write code to implement that algorithm specifically. When you do that, you can always see where your code doesn't do what it's supposed to and you can articulate that to us.

Comment: As it stands, your code creates one Label and then adds that to seven Panels, then repeats that seven more times. Does that sound like what you should be doing? Does that sound like what your code would be doing if it was written to implement logic that you worked out beforehand and already knew worked?

Comment: I forgot to mention that, as a control can only have one parent at a time, adding the same control to multiple containers will produce the same result as only adding it to the last one. so all your `Labels` are going to end up in `req7`. Instead of regular `Panels`, you should use `TableLayoutPanels` or `FlowLayoutPanels`. That way, you don't have to worry about setting the `Location` as it's handled automatically. If you want to add 8 `Labels` to a container, you need to create 8 `Labels` for each container. 7x8=56 `Labels`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Add

        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For i = 0 To 7
          AddlbltoPanel(req1)
          AddlbltoPanel(req2)
          AddlbltoPanel(req3)
          AddlbltoPanel(req4)
          AddlbltoPanel(req5)
          AddlbltoPanel(req6)
          AddlbltoPanel(req7)
        Next
 End Sub

Private Sub AddlbltoPanel(ByVal req as Panel)  
  'if it doesnt work with byval then check with byref
           Dim lbl As New Label 
                
            lbl.Text = "Suppliant Name:"
            lbl.Location = New Point(117, 10 * 1)
            lbl.Height = 15
            lbl.Width = 95

           req.Controls.Add(lbl)
      Me.SuspendLayout()

End Sub
```

I assume req* are your panels,
try above code